# Memory leak in very simple spark streaming app (reading file stream and write to delta)?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, delta-lake

I have a very simple spark streaming app that reads parquet data from s3 and upsert to delta table:

```
import boto3
import os

from pathlib import Path

from delta import *
from delta.tables import *
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *


app_name = "my_app"
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName(app_name).config("spark.databricks.io.cache.enabled", "true").getOrCreate()
spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")
env = os.environ["ENVIRONMENT"]

landing_bucket = f"s3a://awesommmme-data-landing-zone-{env}"  # data_real/landing
cleansing_bucket = f"s3a://awesommmme-data-cleansing-zone-{env}"
checkpoint_bucket = f"s3a://awesommmme-data-spark-checkpoints-{env}"

landing_data_label_path = os.path.join(landing_bucket, "contract_label", "data")
cleansing_data_label_path = os.path.join(cleansing_bucket, "contract_label", "data")

_label_logic_schema = [
    StructField("token_address", StringType()),
    StructField("token_type", StringType()),
]
_raw_data_schema = _label_logic_schema + [
    StructField("update_dt", TimestampType()),
    StructField("year", StringType()),
    StructField("month", StringType()),
    StructField("day", StringType()),
    StructField("hour", StringType()),
    StructField("minute", StringType()),
]
raw_data_schema = StructType(_raw_data_schema)


deltaTable = None
def upsert_to_cleaned_delta(pdf, batchId):
    global deltaTable

    if deltaTable is None:
        try:
            deltaTable = DeltaTable.forPath(spark, cleansing_data_label_path)
        except Exception as e:
            import logging

            logging.error(str(e))
            pdf.write.format("delta").partitionBy("year", "month", "day", "hour", "minute").save(
                cleansing_data_label_path
            )
            deltaTable = DeltaTable.forPath(spark, cleansing_data_label_path)
            return

    deltaTable.alias("old_data").merge(
        pdf.alias("new_data"), "old_data.token_address = new_data.token_address"
    ).whenMatchedUpdateAll(
    ).whenNotMatchedInsertAll().execute()

 
def main():     
    _ = (
        spark.readStream.schema(raw_data_schema)
        .parquet(landing_data_label_path)
        .writeStream.format("delta")
        .option("maxFilesPerTrigger", 10)
        .option("checkpointLocation", "MY_CHECKPOINT_PATH")
        .foreachBatch(lambda pdf, batch_id: upsert_to_cleaned_delta(pdf, batch_id))
        .trigger(processingTime="1 second")
        .outputMode("append")
        .start()
    )
    spark.streams.awaitAnyTermination()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I run this app in spark + kubernetes cluster but when I monitored resources, there is memory leak:

- container
  [image]
- pod

[image]

As time goes, it reached to limit and pods will be dead.

Here is `values.yaml` used in deploying spark app using helm:

```yaml
app: data-pipeline
applicationId: myapp
name: myapp-data
namespace: "{{ .Release.Namespace }}"

environment: dev


sparkConf:
  spark.executor.heartbeatInterval: "600s"
  spark.network.timeout: "3600s"

deps:
  jars:
    - delta-core_2.12-2.0.1.jar

restartPolicy:
  type: Always


driver:
  annotations: {}
  coreRequest: 100m
  coreLimit: 500m
  memory: 3g
executor:
  coreRequest: 100m
  coreLimit: 500m
  instances: 1
  memory: 2g
```

One things to note

- Size of files that spark app reads is really small(Kbytes) and very seldeomly created (one file per 2~3 hours)
- The delta table size is about 190MB, about 700,000 rows.

I have no idea why a memory leak occurs...